# Trouble installing Keepass2 KPGoogleSync Plugin (file corrupted)

Tags: keepass

I have been a user of KeePass for a long time. Until a few years back, I had only one desktop, and KeePass seems to take care of my password management very well. Now I use multiple devices. What I did was that I stored all my passwords using KeePass on my Android phone and typed them in. But this method is very bad because I started using the same weak password for all my online accounts.

Today morning, I thought of fixing this. I uninstalled KeePassDroid and intsalled keepass2andorid on my phone. I set it up to sync passwords to my Google Drive. I installed keeepass2 on my Ubuntu laptop.

But I can't seem to set up [KPGoogleSync](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#kpgsync) plug in. The error occurs when I try to extract the downloaded plugin archive. When I use Archive Manager, it says:

```
An error occurred while loading the archive.
```

I tried `unzip` command and it says:

```
Archive:  Downloads/GoogleSyncPlugin-2.1.0.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of Downloads/GoogleSyncPlugin-2.1.0.zip or
        Downloads/GoogleSyncPlugin-2.1.0.zip.zip, and cannot find Downloads/GoogleSyncPlugin-2.1.0.zip.ZIP, period.
```

A corrupt archive? Check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/a2a87539/) out. Strange enough, some people could extract while others can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the file was really corrupted on some content servers or there was no way investigate further. Statement from the author:

> Uploaded a new version 2.1.1.
>
> Included a checksum as well this time GoogleSyncPlugin-2.1.1. If the
>   file gets corrupted again, I can at least contact SourceForge for an
>   explanation.

<sub>2015-06-16 by Danyal in thread [Download zip corrupt?](http://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/a2a87539/#afa5)</sub>

Comment: could you get it working?

Comment: I was able to extract version 2.1.1 on Ubuntu, yes. I did not test it's functionality.

Comment: Please tell me if you could do it without using libraries from untrusted sources(the readme provides a link to a forum post telling how to install on linux, but the page to the library which he says need to be installed doesnot have a valid certificate).

Comment: @daltonfury42 I just looked at the readme file and found [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/19cca399/#4df1). It's not clear to me about which site mentioned in this you are talking about and it doesn't look like this plugin is easy to setup on a non-Windows OS. I just tried to answer your initial question regarding the corrupted file.

Comment: OK, in the link, the poster ask you to download a dll from a site with an invalid certificate. Just add that warning in your answer.